# Show only the domain name when replacing a URL with hyperlink

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have the function below to simply find a url in some text and change it to a hyperlink; but it also shows the entire url. How can I make the function show only the domain name dynamically?

```
// URL TO HYPERLINK
function activeUrl($string) {
$find = array('`((?:https?|ftp)://\S+[[:alnum:]]/?)`si', '`((?<!//)(www\.\S+[[:alnum:]]/?))`si');

$replace = array('<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', '<a href="http://$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
return preg_replace($find,$replace,$string);
}
```

Comment: what does `$string` look like?

Comment: Sounds like [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url) might be useful to you.

Comment: $string is in a while loop and the while loop shows results from a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that's because your regex matches to the whole url. You need to break up your whole regex and make groups.

I am using this regex, which works fine in my test on regex101.com

```
((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+))((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)
```

The matches for the string `https://www.stackoverflow.com/question/32186805` are

```
1) https://www.stackoverflow.com/question/32186805
2) https://www.stackoverflow.com
3) https://
4) www.stackoverflow.com
5) /question/32186805
```

Now we have the domain only in the fourth group and can use `$4` to only show the domain as the hyperlink text.

```
function activeUrl($string) {
    $find = '/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+))((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/si';

    $replace = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$4</a>';
    return preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner so I'm not very good at this, but there must be an error at the `$find` you edited. I get a blank page after replacing the code.

Comment: Because I forgot the semicolons, try again I updated the code 3mins ago. Also you should activate php errors in the `php.ini`.

Comment: ok. now the links with "HTTP" works but when I use only www.example.com it doesn't work.

FYI: I use:
`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off`

and thank you for your efforts. I'll accept your answer, so please edit it to work with `www` url's too

Comment: @idexo Updated, the regex works now without the protocol, according to regex101.com

Comment: yes it converts `www` links but now it converts the the whole text to hyperlink word by word too. btw: www links now converted as if they were in my domain for example: `www.mydomain.com/page/www.example.com`

Comment: Actually it looks fine on regex101.com, could you please test your string with my regex on http://regex101.com please? I really don't see anything wrong.

Comment: I put the `((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)?(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+))((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)` to first box and `si` to second box and wrote "you should visit the www.example.com it is the best site on the interwebz." and it didn't catch the www.example.com it showed 1 match which was the first word "you"

Comment: Well, that's quite a problem. I'm not getting any good results without the protocol when you have text in it. I don't think it's so easy to implement. That's probably why stackoverflow.com doesn't support auto url conversion without the protocol too.

Comment: allright I'll still accept your answer please make it like the last time it worked it was like this: `((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?([A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+))((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)` thank you very much for your time. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Already did the rollback when I submitted the comment above, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `preg_match_all` to extract the url then `parse_url` function to take only the domain name.

```
function extractUrl ($string) {
    preg_match_all('!https?://\S+!', $string, $matches);
    $url = $matches[0];
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($url[0]); // Use foreach in case you have more than one url. 
    $domain="http://".$parsedUrl['host'];
    return $domain;
}

$string="this is a url http://yourUrl.com/something/anything";
echo extractUrl($string); //http://yourUrl.com
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll most probably accept Charlotte's answer, but I'll note your solution too.