# Replace http://[...] with Link Without http:// in Link Text

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace

I'm using this preg_replace to find links in tweet text and it dutifully returns an HTML link but I wonder if it's possible to, in the same line, lose the http:// from the link text. For example:

```
$output .= preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $status->text);
```

might return:

```
<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://kanyewest.com/">https://kanyewest.com</a>
```

but I'd really like it to return:

```
<a target="blank" rel="nofollow" href="https://kanyewest.com/">kanyewest.com</a>
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32187000/3885509

Comment: That function works great, @Charlotte, except it strips the second part of the link where there is a '/' later on. For example 't.co/twJ6g0rqtz' comes back as just 't.co' in the link text.

Comment: Replace `$4` with `$4$5` inside the replace argument.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Thanks @Charlotte. I just re-read the answer and found that. Awesome, perfect!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show only the domain name when replacing a URL with hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186805/show-only-the-domain-name-when-replacing-a-url-with-hyperlink)

Answer (score -1):

You could just use a Substring. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php